# Galois group of $X^4+X^3+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I'm confused.

Realizing $\mathbb{F}_4=\mathbb{F}_2[T]/(T^2+T+1)$, the polynomial $X^4+X^3+1$ splits as $(X^2+TX+T)(X^2+(T+1)X+T+1)$.

These 2 factors have no root over $\mathbb{F}_4$, so they're irreducible, so our Galois group has order 2 or 4. Since the Galois group of a finite field is cyclic and considering the cyclic subgoups of $S_4$, the only possibility is that it is generated by $(12)(34)\in S_4$.

So our Galois group has order 2 and everything should split after adjoining one of the roots. But after adjoining a root of say $X^2+TX+T$ to $\mathbb{F}_4$, I can't seem to find a root of $X^2+(T+1)X+T+1$?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your "So by cyclicity and the fact that X4+X3+1 has no zeros over F4, the Galois group ought to be generated by $(12)(34)⊂S_4$."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ be a root of $X^2+TX+T=0$, then $$X^2+TX+T = (X+A)(X+A+T)$$ in characteristic $2$. Now apply the Frobenius automorphism $\sigma(X)=X^2$ to $A$ and $A+T$. You get
$$\begin{align}\sigma(A)&=TA+T\\ \sigma(A+T)&=TA+1\end{align}$$
and indeed
$$X^2+(T+1)X+(T+1)=(X+TA+T)(X+TA+1)$$
so $\sigma(A)$ and $\sigma(A+T)$ are the required roots. You can easily verify that $\sigma$ has order $4$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ and corresponds to $(1234)\in S_4$. Then $\sigma^2$ is a Frobenius automorphism over $\mathbb{F}_4$ and corresponds to $(13)(24)$.

Comment: Thanks! I realise now I was working in a "field" of order 8, when in fact adjoining a root to $\mathbb{F}_4$ gives $\mathbb{F}_{16}$. Even better though, your answer actually explains how to find the other roots by going back to $\mathbb{F}_2$!